# Can I force HttpURLConnection to process smaller bytes of data?

Tags: java, http

I'm having an issue with `HttpURLConnection` in Java 11.

I'm trying to connect to an HTTPS endpoint that generates Server Sent Events (SSE). This endpoint generates a long running request which sends data that looks like this:

```
id: 1
event: add
data: 32135

id: 2
event: add
data: 091823

id: 3
event: remove
data: 238812
```

There might be long periods between updates, so I might get only something that looks like:

```
id: 3
event: remove
data: 238812
```

And then there could be an extended period of time before the next event is sent.

The problem I'm having is that when I call `HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()` it always appears to need at least 8192 bytes returned from the HTTP endpoint before it will process any bytes, but I need it to immediately pick up when it sees an event like:

```
id: 3
event: remove
data: 238812
```

I can't find a way to specify the buffer size of the `InputStream` that's returned, so even though I create `BufferedReader` instance with a buffer size of like 16 bytes, because the `InputStream` seems to need at least 8K of data, it doesn't help me.

So something like this doesn't work:

```
URL requestUrl = new URL("http://localhost/my/endpoint");

HttpURLConnection httpConn = requestUrl.openConnection();

httpConn.setDoInput(true);
httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
httpConn.setRequestMethod(this.getMethod());
httpConn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
httpConn.setReadTimeout(60000);

InputStream is = httpConn.getInputStream();

// this waits until at least 8192 bytes arrive
int readChar = 0;
while( (readChar = is.read()) > -1 ){
    // do something
}
```

Using a `BufferedReader` does not change anything, since the problem appears to be in the `InputStream`.

```
BufferedReader incomingStream = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")
    , 64
);
```

Is there a way I can reduce the buffer size of the `InputStream` so that it will start process when less than 8192 bytes have been sent by the server?

I feel like I'm missing something very basic.

Comment: That might be more to do with the server than your client. I would dump the headers from the server

Comment: Do other clients work as expected?

Comment: @g00se+ I'd expect the headers to just say TE:chunked, and what matters is (1) what the server puts in each chunk and (2) since this is HTTPS, if/when it flushes the TLS record. Sysprop javax.debug.net=ssl:record:plaintext can show both of these.

Comment: Right. Good idea

Comment: When I use cURL, the content is flushed to the output as I'd expect (meaning I see the data as soon as it's pushed to the output stream of the endpoint I'm connecting too.

However, in my Java code the stream only starts processing if the server pushed 8K of data. So it seems like the input stream is requiring the 8192 bytes.

Comment: I want to thank everyone who chimed in, the comments have been really helpful in making me examine things more closely.

I went back and verified the headers being returned and noticed server was not returning a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header. It turns out my request was sending a `Content-Type: application/json` header, which was preventing the server from returning this header, even though the content was being flushed.

Removing the  `Content-Type: application/json` request header gets things working the way I expected.

Is there a way to get things to work even with the header?